# Pregmatching All Just Returns the first Asertion

Tags: preg-match-all

Im trying to Grab the Hour Minute Second From

`$time = 02:00:00`

with

`preg_match_all('/^(\d\d):?/', $time, $all_matches);`

but it only returns the first Asertion.

`array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '02:',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '02',
  ),
)`

Saying that preg_match_all finds all assertions on a String,
What is missing on the regex which fails to give the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all('/^(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/', $time, $all_matches);`
Works.